# Bandwidth selection using NP package

Tags: r, vector, regression

New to R and having problem with a very simple task! I have read a few columns of .csv data into R, the contents of which contains of variables that are in the natural numbers plus zero, and have missing values.  After trying to use the non-parametric package, I have two problems: first, if I use the simple command `bw=npregbw(ydat=y, xdat=x, na.omit)`, where x and y are column vectors, I get the error that "number of regression data and response data do not match".  Why do I get this, as I have the same number of elements in each vector?

Second, I would like to call the data ordered and tell npregbw this, using the command `bw=npregbw(ydat=y, xdat=ordered(x))`.  When I do that, I get the error that x must be atomic for sort.list.  But how is x not atomic, it is just a vector with natural numbers and NA's?

Any clarifications would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1) You probably have a different number of NA's in y and x.

2) Can't be sure about this, since there is no example. If it is of following type:

```
 x <- c(3,4,NA,2)
```

Then `ordered(x)` should work fine. Please provide an example of your case.

EDIT: You of course tried `bw=npregbw(ydat=y, xdat=x)`? `ordered()` makes your vector an ordered factor (see `?ordered`), which is not an atomic vector (see 2.1.1 [link](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.pdf) and `?factor`)

EDIT2: So the problem was the way of subsetting data.  Note the difference in various ways of subsetting. data$x and data[,i] (where i = column number of column x) give you vectors, while data[c("x")] and data[i] give a data frame. Functions expect vectors, unless they call for data = (your data). In that case they work with column names

Comment: 1) I have tried a few diagnostics.  I cleared all NA's from my data and then tried npregbw, using x and y vectors that both have the summary length: 6903, class: -none-, mode: numeric.  I still get the error that number of regression data do not match response data.  Second, I created two small, simple vectors to use npregbw with which include NA's, and it works fine.

2) I also tried ordering these generated vectores as you describe above and this also worked fine.

I guess it's a data problem? The problem is that I don't see the difference between the created vectors and my actual data.

Comment: That's weird. It must be something with the class or subsetting of your vectors. Which way did you subset your vectors? data$x? You could also try numeric(y) ordered(x) combination (in case the problem is with classes). Another thing I would try would be npregbw(y~ordered(x))

Comment: Well, that is the fix. Thanks.  Subsetting with data$x did the trick.  Solved both the error with data of different length, as well as allowing me to call ordered().

Comment: Good to hear that you got it solved. It's useful to note the difference in these various ways in subsetting. data$x and data[,i] (where i = column number of column x) give you vectors, while data[c("x")] and data[i] give a data frame. Functions expect vectors, unless they call for data = <your data>. In that case they work with column names